# Strictly decreasing sequence of positive real numbers properties

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If I have the following strictly decreasing sequence of positive real numbers  $$((k + 1) a_k) \in c_0$$
where
$$c_0=  \bigg\{ \left \{ x_n \right \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq\mathbb{R} \colon  \text{lim}_{n\to \infty}x_n=0 \bigg\}$$
Is there any way or any criteria that the above implies that the series
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$$ converges?
Could you tell me some properties of decreasing positive sequences?

Comment: It is not clear how we should interpret your question. At the very least, the fact that the sequence $(k+1)a_k$ is decreasing is not enough information in and of itself to deduce that $\sum_k a_k$ converges. For example, the sequence $a_k =  \dfrac{1}{(k+1)\ln(k+1)}$ satisfies your condition but the series $\sum_k a_k$ fails to converge